# Is there any way to see logs in follow mode after docker-compose stop?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

For example, I started my system: `docker-compose up -d`

And then I see logs in follow mode:
`docker-compose logs -f`

But if I stop system with `docker-compose stop` then my `docker-compose logs -f` will exit. Is there any way to "wait" until system starts?

Comment: you can always do, when they are restarted `docker logs -f container_name_or_id`

Comment: @user2915097 yeah I know, I do this now, but may be there is another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, as of 2019, there's no way to do this.

[docker/compose#2227](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2227) suggests that it's intentional that `docker-compose logs -f` exits once there are no more containers running:

> if the log stream is done (the containers have stopped) logs should exit

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it like this:

`while true ;  do docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml logs -f  ; sleep 5 ; echo "Are you loopy?" ; done`

However, due to a bug in docker(-compose), the `docker-compose logs` process currently does not return to prompt when a `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml down` is invoked in a second terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to `/var/lib/docker/containers`. List of directories with `CONTAINER ID` names are present here. Change to that directory and you'll find the log file over there. You can view this file which contains the logs.

```
Eg. Container ID=2ef1023d82e8
#cd /var/lib/docker/containers/2ef1023d82e8e71d81bcd7c9e933dc68aed5cfd2c7b69c286e11d3b483092515
#ls
2ef1023d82e8e71d81bcd7c9e933dc68aed5cfd2c7b69c286e11d3b483092515-json.log
```